# Running wave robot inside django app engine patched webapp

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-wave

I've got a Google Wave python robot running with an existing django app engine web app.

All works well apart from one thing, for some reason I am unable to access my datastore which is the same datastore for the django webapp.

I want to read data and store data to the django datastore from the robot.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using the helper, appengine-patch, or non-rel?